# Configure Display toggle button on ASUS laptop

Tags: kernel, keyboard, xorg, display, acpi

I have ASUS GL552VW laptop with Xubuntu 17.04 and I use `acpi_backlight=native` kernel option to make brightness keys work, but the display power (<kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>) don't work. When I try to assign key in keyboard option the key don't respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case I use the following:

1. run `xev` and press the key to get the keycode
2. create file `~/.Xmodmap` with content `keycode 253 = XF86Display`
3. reboot the system

now when I press the key I've got `xfce4-display-settings` window run (the only issue is that I need to press the key twice), because that's what in keyboard settings. To make it turn on/off display I have this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/toggle-display-keyboard
KBBL="/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight"


if [ -e $file ]; then
    rm $file
    sudo vbetool dpms on
    [ -d $KBBL -o -f $KBBL ] && echo 3 | sudo tee $KBBL/brightness > /dev/null
else
    touch $file
    if [ -e $file ]; then
        sudo vbetool dpms off
        [ -d $KBBL -o -f $KBBL ] && echo 0 | sudo tee $KBBL/brightness > /dev/null
    fi
fi
```

and I've replaced the `xfce4-display-settings` with this script. And now I have power on/off using <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.